# Create folder in client system

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

My application is hosted on IIS 7.0. There is a scenario where end user save the image (from my application) into his/her machine. Now my question is can we make a default folder in end user machine so that every time when user save the image , it will automatically save on the default folder location that we have created from our application. And please let me know how to create the folder in client system.

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

No, this is impossible.

(At least under standard security conditions. If you limit your users to, for example, Internet Explorer on systems with your custom written signed ActiveX control, then it might become possible)